# distance between a two sets in metric space proof

Tags: metric-spaces

Let (X,d) be a metric space, A and B be subsets of X so that d(A,B)>0 where

d(A,B)=inf{d(a,b):a∈A,b∈B}.

Show that,

if A and B are compact, then dist(A,B)=d(a,b) where a and b are elements of A and B sets respectively

How can I proove this? Can someone provide me a reference to this proof?

Comment: What exactly must be proved?

Comment: if A and B are compact, then dist(A,B)=d(a,b) where a and b are elements of A and B sets respectively@drhab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually a weaker assumption that $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed gives the same conclusion. By the definition of infimum you can find sequences $\{a_n\}$ in $A$ and $\{b_n\}$ in $B$ such that
$$d(a_n,b_n)\to d(A,B)$$
Since $A$ is compact, there is a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ converging to some $a\in A$. And we have
$$d(a,b_{n_k})\leq d(a_{n_k},b_{n_k})+d(a,a_{n_k})\to d(A,B)+0=d(A,B)\quad(k\to\infty)$$
meaning $\{b_{n_k}\}$ is a bounded set of points, and hence has a further convergent subsequence $\{b_{n_{k_j}}\}$ to some $b$. Since $B$ is closed, $b\in B$.

Combining the above we have
$$d(a,b)\leq d(a,a_{n_{k_j}})+d(a_{n_{k_j}},b_{n_{k_j}})+d(b_{n_{k_j}},b)\to 0+d(A,B)+0=d(A,B)$$
Hence
$d(a,b)\leq d(A,B)\leq d(a,b)\implies d(a,b)=d(A,B)$

Answer (score 0):

d is a function on a compact topological space $ A\times B$. On a compact function always reaches it's inf, so there exist $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that dist(A,B)=d(a,b)

Comment: hey,  can u provide me some reference please?

Comment: Any book on general topology.

Comment: No, actually what I need to find the answer for this question. How to prove this?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_{n})$ and $(b_{n})$ be sequences in $A$ and $B$ respectively such that 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}d(a_{n},b_{n})=d(A,B).$$
as $A$ and $B$ are sequentially compact we may assume, by taking a subsequence if necessary, that $(a_{n})$ converges to some $a\in A$ and $(b_{n})$ converges to some $b\in B$. We find
$$d(A,B)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}d(a_{n},b_{n})\geq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}d(a,b_{n})-d(a_{n},a)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}d(a,b)-d(a_{n},a)-d(b,b_{n})=d(a,b)\geq d(A,B).$$

Comment: Can't find a reference just yet.